# コピー（ヤンク？）したものをvimのコマンドラインに貼り付けたい

Tags: vim

たとえば画像のようなテキスト

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
abcd
efgh
```

をvimで扱っているとします。
コピーの方法はビジュアルモードで `abc` の部分を選択したとします。

ここでこのコピーした `abc` を下部の `:` で始まるvimのコマンドラインに貼り付けるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？
用途としては、コマンドラインで `s/abc/xyz/` みたいに置換処理を書くときに、先程コピーしたモノを使いたいみたいなことを想定しています。

Macで標準搭載されているターミナルからvimを使用しています。

日本語キーボードと英字キーボードどちらの環境もそれぞれあります。

Comment: 環境により最適な回答が変わる可能性があるので、OSとか、vimなのかgvimなのか、vimならターミナルエミュレータは何を使っているかなどの情報を書くと良いと思います。

Comment: @hidezzz 追記しました。もっと細かいバージョンが必要なら再度指摘をお願いします。

Comment: キーボードについても言及しました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「:」を押した後の入力モードでヤンクバッファの内容をペーストするのは、<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> 　<kbd>"</kbd>と順番で入力することで出来ます。

以下は質問を把握する前に書いたものですが、そのまま残しておきます。vim関係ないコピー＆ペーストのやり方になります。

環境によるので、OSとか、vimなのかgvimなのか、vimならターミナルエミュレータは何を使っているかなどの情報を書くと良いと思います。

自分はguakeというターミナルエミュレータの中でtmuxを起動して作業しているので、guakeでマウスオペレーションでコピー＆ペーストするか、tmuxのコピーモードを使ってコピー＆ペーストすることが多いです。

vimのヤンクバッファとOSのクリップボードを共有化するようなやり方もあった気がしますが、自分は使ったことがありません。

Comment: MacでControlとRを同時に押すとコマンドラインに「"」と表示されてそのあとどうして良いかわかりませんでした。

Comment: 念のため、手順をおさらいします。(1)「v」」でビジュアルモードに入り文字列を選択し「y」を押して文字列をヤンクする。(2)「:」を押してコマンドモードに入る。(3)コマンドモードの状態で「CTRL-R」 「"」の順に押すと(1)でヤンクした文字列がペーストされる。

Comment: ちなみにマニュアルでいうと「:help i_CTRL-R」で説明されている機能です。

Comment: なるほど。マニュアルを読んだらいけました。contrl+r のあとに0を入力でした

Comment: あ。でももう一度冷静にマニュアルを読むと " を押すともありました。 実際にやってみると " でもいけました。失礼しました。

Comment: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd>と書くと分かりやすいと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。回答のほうを修正しました。

Answer (score 0):

:<C-R>"
コマンド・ライン・モード[Ctrl]を押したまま[R]に続けて["](日本語キーボードなら[Shift]+[2])でペーストされます
:help c_ctrl_r
が参考になるともいます

私も頻繁に使うので、cnoremap でマップしています